# Extract after equal sign

Tags: python, regex, pandas

just started python pandas on Juypter. I am having difficulties trying to get the values after the equal sign. Can anyone help me through?

```
        Hi = 123456
        123456 (result i wish to get)
```

My current code below returns "**= 123456**".

```
        df['column'].str.extract("Hi+\W(.*)",expand= True)
```

Comment: Use `"Hi *= *(.*)"`. If you need to match any non-word char you can use `r"Hi *[^\w ] *(.*)"`

Comment: Thanks Alot! It works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used a `+` quantifier on a symbol `i` making it match 1 or more times, thus `\W` matches the space after `Hi`.

You can use

```
r"Hi *[^\w ] *(.*)"
```

where:

- `Hi` - matches `Hi`
- `*` - matches 0 or more spaces
- `[^\w ]` - a non-word char except a space
- `*` - matches 0 or more spaces
- `(.*)` - 0+ chars other than a newline, as many as possible (the rest of the line).

If the space after `Hi` is *obligatory*, use `+` quantifier `r"Hi +[^\w ] *(.*)"`.

However, the best way is to use a mere split: `'Hi = 123456'.split(' = ')` ([demo](https://ideone.com/Jw4pdd))